azure bicep deployment modifies network interface resources even though there are no changes
I am building a Azure bicep script to deploy network interfaces that get used by VMs and added to LB backend pool.
Here's the bicep code:
resource masterNic0 'Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces@2024-05-01' = {
  name: 'mymasternic-${resourceSuffix}-0'
  location: location
  properties: {
    networkSecurityGroup: {
      id: nsg.id
    }
    ipConfigurations: [
      {
        name: 'ipconfig1'
        properties: {
          subnet: {
            id: subnetNetworkID
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

The bicep what-if output always indicates changes to be done:
Note: The result may contain false positive predictions (noise).
You can help us improve the accuracy of the result by opening an issue here: https://aka.ms/WhatIfIssues

Resource and property changes are indicated with these symbols:
  - Delete
  ~ Modify

The deployment will update the following scope:

Scope: /subscriptions/mysubscriptionid/resourceGroups/myresourcegroup

  ~ Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/mymasternic-dev-0 [2024-05-01]
    - kind:                                          "Regular"
    - properties.allowPort25Out:                     false
    - properties.auxiliaryMode:                      "None"
    - properties.auxiliarySku:                       "None"
    - properties.defaultOutboundConnectivityEnabled: false
    - properties.disableTcpStateTracking:            false
    ~ properties.ipConfigurations: [
      ~ 0:

        - properties.privateIPAddress:        "144.43.72.13"
        - properties.privateIPAddressVersion: "IPv4"

      ]

Resource changes: 1 to modify.

Are you sure you want to execute the deployment? (y/n): 

Not sure why this is coming? Is it because I am not specifying a single IP address? I want the IP to be picked up dynamically.
I tried the deployment with both Incremental and Complete mode but seem to get same result.

The "what-if" output flags changes due to Azure dynamically assigning default values. To avoid this, explicitly set privateIPAddressVersion to 'IPv4' and privateIPAllocationMethod to 'Dynamic' in your Bicep code @ozn

The behavior you're seeing in the What-If output is due to the fact that the privateIPAddress is being managed by the Azure platform when not explicitly provided, and the script is likely defaulting to values that do not align with the current state of the resource, Remove privateIPAddress explicitly: If you want the IP to be dynamically assigned, you should avoid specifying privateIPAddress at all in the ipConfigurations block, ensuring that the IP is picked up automatically by Azure. From your Bicep code, it appears that you're omitting it, which is correct for dynamic assignment.

@VinayB, I'm seeing the same behavior adding those two fields.

I have just test the scenario at my side, just the same result as you. even change the resource api version. @ozn

Some of the properties that are listed as deleted won't actually change. Properties can be incorrectly reported as deleted when they aren't in the Bicep file, but are automatically set during deployment as default values. This result is considered "noise" in the what-if response. The final deployed resource will have the values set for the properties. As the what-if operation matures, these properties will be filtered out of the result.

I have found a similar officail explanation, which seem the build-in feature, and called this nosie. Hope this can help.
Doc links

When the whatif command runs, the first notices also shows:


Oh I see. Thank you.
That is a really annoying behavior. But good to know.
